# Is it forbidden for a woman to learn Gemara?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, women, torah-study

Is it forbidden for a woman to learn Gemara?

Comment: Could you add some words of explanation of why one would believe that it is _asur_ for women to learn _g'mara_?

Comment: Here are some words of explanation. "כל המלמד את ביתו תורה כאילו מלמדה תיפלות" 
,סוטה כ"א next one:
צוו חכמים שלא ילמד אדם בתו תורה מפני שרוב הנשים אין דעתן מכוונת להתלמד אלא הן מוציאות דברי תורה לדברי הבאי לפי עניות דעתן (רמבם הלכות תלמוד תורה פרק א הלכה יג).

Comment: Why does this question even need to be asked?  In today's day and age women and men can, of course, study similar subjects, wither together or separate.

Comment: @jutky: Those simply explain why one **shouldn't,** not that one is forbidden to.  And the second one is strongly based on societal norms, which have drastically changed since the time of the Rambam.

Comment: @ShmuelL I don't think that "Bina Yetera" and "Daatan Kala" have changed according to women (subjective). So, what does makes you think that this Rambam is not relevant nowadays. I'm not stating that women are stupid or something like that (has vehalila) but they do leak 'daas' in some way (do not confuse with intellect, knowledge an so on). The same way men leak 'bina' in comparison to women, but it seems that 'daat' is more essential in learning than 'bina'. IMHO.

Comment: @jutky "שרוב הנשים אין דעתן מכוונת להתלמד"  Which, quite obviously, simply isn't true in today's day and age. **|** I think you meant "lack," not "leak."

Comment: @jutky According to מִלּוֹן אֶבֶן־שׁוֹשָׁן, *da'at* and *bina* are synonyms.  "Da'at" is general knowledge, whereas "Bina" is  בִּינָה, הַיְּכֹלֶת הַנַּפְשִׁית לְהָבִין דְּבָרִים וּלְהַסִּיק מֵהֶם מַסְקָנוֹת הֶגְיוֹנִיּוֹת | Which would imply that "bina" is actually more important in learning *gemara* and *halacha* than general *da'at.* | Finally, I don't believe that men or women lack either, and you're gonna have to provide a source for your assertion that they do.  (You could start by asking your wife if she's feel that she lacks דעת or שֵׂכֶל.)

Comment: @ShmuelL you right I meant lack (it my programmers habits about mem leak :) ). My wife doesn't leaks שכל but do דעת. It is harder for her to make decisions than for me. That's why she has me - to help her to decide, and I have her - to help me to see different sides of the problem. Have you observed once how men make shopping, now look at women :) (I'll look for sources later, short of time now, sorry)

Comment: Note that nobody I know of says women can't learn. It's that men would be forbidden to teach them. See https://www.etzion.org.il/en/shiur-03-women-and-torah-study It's too long for me to really summarize but basically there are various opinions about that rabbi Eliezer statement including that is only forbidden to force them to learn it and not if they want to/ask to, or that it only applies to lesser intelligent people, or that it only applies to children etc etc. Personally I go with understanding it with all of the limitations and leave it at that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn't seem that anyone attempted to address this in a comprehensive manner, so I will try. There might be slight overlap with some of the other answers here, and with [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26653/how-were-girls-educated-during-the-talmudic-era/92279#92279) to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26653/how-were-girls-educated-during-the-talmudic-era). If you don't want to read through many paragraphs of sources, skip to the summary all the way at the bottom.

---

It all starts with the Mishnah in Sotah [3:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37944&st=&pgnum=96) which states:

> אם יש לה זכות היתה תולה לה יש זכות תולה שנה אחת יש זכות תולה ב' שנים
>   יש זכות תולה ג' שנים מכאן אומר בן עזאי חייב אדם ללמד את בתו תורה שאם
>   תשתה תדע שהזכות תולה לה ר"א אומר כל המלמד בתו תורה לומדה תפלות
>
> IF SHE POSSESSED A MERIT, IT [CAUSES THE WATER] TO SUSPEND ITS EFFECT
>   UPON HER. SOME MERIT SUSPENDS THE EFFECT FOR ONE YEAR, ANOTHER FOR TWO
>   YEARS, AND ANOTHER FOR THREE YEARS. HENCE DECLARED BEN AZZAI, A MAN IS
>   UNDER THE OBLIGATION TO TEACH HIS DAUGHTER TORAH, SO THAT IF SHE HAS
>   TO DRINK [THE WATER OF BITTERNESS], SHE MAY KNOW THAT THE MERIT
>   SUSPENDS ITS EFFECT. R. ELIEZER SAYS: WHOEVER TEACHES HIS DAUGHTER
>   TORAH TEACHES HER OBSCENITY. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Sotah.pdf); capitals in
>   original)

Here we have a tannaic dispute wherein one tanna asserts that teaching girls Torah is obligatory. He does not specify what forms of Torah he is referring to. The other tanna does not state that teaching girls Torah is forbidden; rather, he states that teaching girls Torah has a negative consequence.

In the Jerusalem Talmud ([Sotah 3:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14142&st=&pgnum=528)), however, this second opinion is taken to a further extreme, with the assertion that the Torah should be burned rather than given over to women:

> מטרונה שאלה את רבי לעזר מפני מה חט אחת במעשה העגל והן מתים בה שלש
>   מיתות אמר לה אין חכמתה של אשה אלא בפילכה דכתיב וכל אשה חכמת לב בידיה
>   טוו אמר לו הורקנוס בנו בשביל שלא להשיבה דבר אחד מן התורה איבדת ממני
>   שלש מאות כור מעשר בכל שנה אמר ליה ישרפו דברי תורה ואל ימסרו לנשים
>   וכשיצתה אמרו לו תלמידיו רבי לזו דחיתה לנו מה אתה משיב

Rambam ([Hilchot Talmud Torah 1:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=172)) codifies the law as follows:

> אשה שלמדה תורה יש לה שכר אבל אינו כשכר האיש מפני שלא נצטוית וכל העושה
>   דבר שאינו מצווה עליו לעשותו אין שכרו כשכר המצווה שעשה אלא פחות ממנו
>   ואע"פ שיש לה שכר צוו חכמים שלא ילמד אדם את בתו תורה מפני שרוב הנשים
>   אין דעתם מכוונת להתלמד אלא הן מוציאות דברי תורה לדברי הבאי לפי עניות
>   דעתן אמרו חכמים כל המלמד את בתו תורה כאילו למדה תפלות בד"א בתורה שבעל
>   פה אבל תורה שבכתב לא ילמד אותה לכתחלה ואם למדה אינו כמלמדה תפלות
>
> A woman who studies Torah will receive reward. However, that reward
>   will not be [as great] as a man's, since she was not commanded [in
>   this mitzvah]. Whoever performs a deed which he is not commanded to
>   do, does not receive as great a reward as one who performs a mitzvah
>   that he is commanded to do.
>
> Even though she will receive a reward, the Sages commanded that a
>   person should not teach his daughter Torah, because most women cannot
>   concentrate their attention on study, and thus transform the words of
>   Torah into idle matters because of their lack of understanding.
>
> [Thus,] our Sages declared: "Whoever teaches his daughter Torah is
>   like one who teaches her tales and parables." This applies to the Oral
>   Law. [With regard to] the Written Law: at the outset, one should not
>   teach one's daughter. However, if one teaches her, it is not
>   considered as if she was taught idle things. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910973/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-One.htm))

Here Rambam appears to decide in favor of the second opinion in the Mishnah (as he states simply that "the Sages" said that teaching girls = tiflus). We also see two new points from Rambam's formulation. First, he adds that the Sages commanded not to teach girls (as opposed to the Mishnah which only mentioned the negative consequence but no command against teaching them), and second he distinguishes between the Written Torah and the Oral Torah, arguing that the negative comments in the Mishnah were in reference to the Oral Law. Teaching girls the Written Law was not included, though it is still frowned upon.

However, despite the overall negative attitude displayed in this formulation, we must remember that he started it off by saying that if a woman does study Torah she receives reward, implying that it is in some sense a good thing.

Most of the rishonim/poskim follow Rambam in adopting the second opinion in the Mishnah. Notably, however, [R. Isaiah De Trani (the Younger)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_di_Trani_the_Younger) states that although women are not required to be taught Torah, it is allowed. More importantly, in the second sentence he explicitly rules like the first opinion in the Mishnah, stating that in the times when the sotah ritual was in force one was obligated to teach his daughter Torah:

**Piskei Riaz Sotah 1:2**

> אע"פ שאין האשה מצווה על תלמוד תורה כמו שנ' ולמדתם אותם את בניכם ולא את
>   בנותיכם אם רצה ללמדה הרשות בידו כמבואר בקונטרס הראייות בראיי' ב' ובזמן
>   שהיו משקין את הסוטות חייב אדם ללמד את בתו תורה שאם תשתה ותנצל תדע
>   שהזכות תלת לה

The Tur and Shulchan Aruch codify the law following the formulation of Rambam. (The Tur actually reverses the Written Law and Oral Law but the Beis Yosef attributes that to a printer's error.)

[**Tur Y.D. 246**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6223)

> כ' הרמב"ם ז"ל אשה שלמדה תורה יש לה שכר אבל לא כשכר האיש מפני שאינה
>   מצווה ועושה וכל העושה דבר שאינו מצווה עליו אין שכרו כשכר המצווה ועושה
>   ואע"פ שיש לה שכר צוו חכמים שלא ילמד אדם את בתו תורה מפני שרוב נשים אין
>   דעתם מכוונת להתלמד ומוציאין דברי תורה לדברי הבאי לפי עניות דעתם אמרו
>   חכמים כל המלמד לבתו תורה כאילו מלמדה תפלות בד"א בתורה שבכתב אבל בתורה
>   שבע"פ לא ילמד אותה בתחילה ואם מלמדה אינו כמלמדה תפלות

**[Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 246:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6715)**

> אשה שלמדה תורה יש לה שכר אבל לא כשכר האיש מפני שאינה מצווה ועושה ואע"פ
>   שיש לה שכר צוו חז"ל שלא ילמד אדם את בתו תורה מפני שרוב הנשים אין דעתן
>   מכוונת להתלמד ומוציאות דברי תורה לדברי הבאי לפי עניות דעתן אמרו חכמים
>   כל המלמד את בתו תורה כאילו מלמדה תיפלות (פי' דבר עבירה) בד"א בתורה
>   שבע"פ אבל תורה שבכתב לא ילמד אותה לכתחלה ואם מלמדה אינו כמלמדה תיפלות

This view is also more or less echoed in the Levush and the Aruch Hashulchan.

[**Levush Y.D. 246:6**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9276&st=&pgnum=276)

> אשה שלמדה תורה אף על פי שאינה מצווה יש לה שכר אבל לא כשכר האיש שכל
>   המצוה על דבר ומקיימו יש לו שכר יותר ממי שאינו מצווה ומקיימו מפני
>   שהמצווה דואג תמיד לבטל יצרו ולקיים מצות בוראו מה שאין כן במי שאינו
>   מצווה שאינו דואג אלא עושה אותה מרצונו מכל מקום שכר קצת יש לו מיהו אף
>   על פי שיש לאשה קצת שכר כשלומדת תורה צוו חז"ל שלא ילמד אדם את בתו תורה
>   מפני שרוב הנשים אין דעתן מכוונות להתלמד ומוציאות דברי תורה לדברי הבאי
>   לפי עניות דעתן אמרו חכמים ז"ל  כל המלמד את בתו תורה כאילו מלמדה תיפלות
>   במה דברים אמורים בתורה שבעל פה שהוא דבר עמוק וצריך עיון רב ואין דעתן
>   סובלתו אבל תורה שבכתב לא ילמוד אותה לכתחלה ואם מלמדה אינו כמלמדה
>   תיפלות

**[Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 246:19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=228)**

> אשה אינה מצווה בת"ת וכתבו הפוסקים אשה שלמדה תורה יש לה שכר אבל לא כשכר
>   האיש מפני שאינה מצווה וגדול שכר המצווה ועושה ממי שאינו מצווה ועושה
>   מפני שהמצווה יצרו מסיתו לבלי לקיים והוא דואג תמיד לבטל יצרו ולקיים
>   מצות בוראו משא"כ מי שאינו מצווה אין יצרו מסיתו על ההיפך ואע"פ שיש לה
>   שכר צוו חז"ל [סוטה כ א] לבלי ללמד לבתו תורה ואמרו חכמים דכל המלמדה
>   תורה כאלו מלמדה תפלות כלומר דבר עבירה והטעם דמפני שדעתן קלות ומוציאין
>   ד"ת לדברי הבאי לפי דעתן הדלה בד"א בתורה שבע"פ אבל בתורה שבכתב לא ילמד
>   אותה לכתחלה ואם מלמדה אינו כמלמדה תפלות כן כתבו הרמב"ם והש"ע ובטור
>   כתוב להיפך דתורה שבכתב הוי כמלמדה תפלות ולא תורה שבע"פ ע"ש וכתבו שטעות
>   הדפוס הוא [ב"י] ויש מי שרוצה לקיים הגירסא ואינו מספיק [עי' פרישה

It thus appears that the standard codes follow the opinion that teaching the Oral Law to women is frowned upon. Note that so far we have seen no distinctions between different works of the Oral Law (e.g. that it is okay to study Mishnah but not Talmud).

However, there are a number of exceptions even within this view. [R. Jacob Moelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) explains that the only problem with the Oral Law is when someone teaches it to his daughter. But if she learns it herself then it is okay, and that is when she gets rewarded:

**Shu"t Maharil Hachadashos # 45**

> ודווקא המלמד לבתו אבל היא שלמדה בעצמה יש לה שכר כאינה מצוה ועושה שהיא
>   מכוונת לטוב

Similarly, [R. Joshua Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Falk), picking up on the words שרוב נשים אין דעתם מכוונת להתלמד ומוציאין דברי תורה לדברי הבאי, explains that a father cannot teach his daughter because she might be of the majority of women for whom learning Torah has negative consequences. But if a woman learns herself, she shows that she is not part of that majority and she gets rewarded for learning:

[**Perisha 246:15**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6224)

> אבל אם למדה לעצמה אנו רואין שיצאה מהרוב ולכך כתב לעיל שיש לה שכר
>   ורצונו לומר אם למדה התורה על מכונה שאינה מוציאה לדברי הבאי אבל האב
>   אינו רשאי ללמדה דדילמא תוציא דבריה לדברי הבאי כי הוא אינו יודע מה
>   שבלבה וק"ל

Another similar exception is formulated by R. Samuel Ben Elchanan Jacob. He suggests that the rabbinic objection to female study was in a situation where young girls are taught Torah. However, it is okay for a woman to choose to study Torah:

[**Shu"t Mayan Ganim 5:10**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24913&st=&pgnum=85)

> כי אפשר לחלק שחכמים ז"ל לא דברו אלא כשהאב מלמדה בקטנותה שגם במעלליה
>   תתנגר אם זך ואם ישר פעלה דודאי כי האי גוונא איכא למיחש שרוב הנשים דעתן
>   קלות כלות זמנן בדברי הבאי וכרובן כן חטאו מקוצר רוח אמנם הנשים אשר נדבה
>   לבן אותנה לקרבה אל המלכה המלוכ' מלאכת ה' מצד בחירתן בטוב במה שהוא טוב
>   הן הנה תעלן בהר ה' תשכונה במקום קדשו כי נשי מופ' הנה ועל חכני דורן
>   להדרן לאדרן לסדרן לחזק ידיהן לאמץ זרועותיהן לחגור מתניהן לאזור חלציהן

A final important exception is that virtually everyone agreed that women must study the laws that pertain to them. This is most famously codified by R. Moses Isserles:

**[Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 246:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6715)**

> ומ"מ חייבת האשה ללמוד דינים השייכים לאשה

This leads to the argument that one cannot properly understand the actual laws without the background discussions of the topics in the Oral Law, primarily the Talmud (see below).

Aside from the inherent exceptions to the law, in more contemporary times a number of leading rabbinic figures have advocated that due to changing circumstances we need to change the policy as well. This most famously began with [R. Israel Meir Kagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Meir_Kagan) arguing that the Mishnah was written in an era when people lived close to their parents and the traditions were strong enough to be absorbed in the home. However, in his time he felt that people no longer lived near their parents and the traditions had weakened, creating an environment in which it was necessary to teach girls Torah, and without Torah study they would abandon Judaism.

**Likutei Halachos Sotah**

> ונראה דכל זה דוקא בזמנים שלפנינו שכל אחד היה דר במקום אבותיו וקבלת
>   האבות היה חזק מאד אצל כל אחד ואחד להתנהג בדרך שדרכו אבותיו וכמאמר
>   הכתוב שאל אביך ויגדך בזה היינו יכולים לומר שלא תלמוד תורה ותסמוך
>   בהנהגה על אבותיה הישרים אבל כעת בעו"ה שקבלת האבות נתרופף מאוד מאוד וגם
>   מצוי שאינו דר במקום אבותיו כלל ובפרט אותן שמרגילין עצמן ללמוד כתב
>   ולשון העמים בודאי מצוה רבה ללמדם חומש וגם נביאים וכתובים ומוסרי חז"ל
>   כגון מסכת אבות וספר מנורת המאור וכדומה כדי שיתאמת אצלם ענין אמונתינו
>   הקדושה דאל"ה עלול שיסורו מדרך ד' ויעברו על כל יסודי הדת ח"ו

However, despite this line of reasoning, he did not take it to the fullest conclusion and recommend Talmud study. (While he did not specifically forbid Talmud study) He only recommended the Written Law and very limited parts of the Oral Law.

Several decades later, though, [R. Joseph B. Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) took the argument further and advocated Talmud study for girls. [R. Hershel Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) records R. Soloveitchik as saying that even if teaching girls was a biblical prohibition, we would have to allow it nowadays because now that women are on par with men in other fields of study they will not keep the Torah if they are not allowed to understand it from the source in Scripture and Talmud. He also pointed out (similar to R. Kagan's point) that in prior times women could learn everything they needed to know from observing their mothers in the kitchen, but in today's technological society that is no longer possible, and if we don't teach them the foundations of the Torah from the Chumash and Talmud we might be in danger of losing true Judaism:

**Mipininei Harav p. 167 (p.214 in the newer edition):**

> פעם אחת נסעתי יחד עם הרב זצ"ל מבוסטון לישיבה (בניו יורק).... אז סיפר
>   לי הרב דאפילו אם היה אסור מן התורה ללמד תורה שבעל פה לנשים היום בתקופה
>   שנשים שוות לאנשים הן באקדמיה והן במדיניות והנשים לא יסכימו להתנהג לפי
>   התורה אם הענין לא יהיה מובן להן ממקורו במקרא ובגמרא מוכרחים אנו להתיר
>   להן ללמוד תורה שבעל פה סוף הדבר כמו שהרמב"ם בעיתו מזכיר בהקדמתו למשנה
>   תורה שלו שרבנו הקדוש תיקן כתיבת המשנה והתורה שבעל פה בכתב "כדי שלא
>   תשתכח תורה שבעל פה מישראל" כן תקן רבנו יוסף דוב הלוי זצ"ל שאנו
>   מחוייבים ללמד תורה שבעל פה לנשים הרב המשיך לבאר לי שבימים הקדמונים
>   נערה רק הצטרכה להסתכל בהנהגת האם במטבח ובבית בכל יום ובשבת ובפסח לדעת
>   איך להתנהג לפי התורה הלכה למעשה היום הסביר הרב יש בעיות מסובכות
>   המופיעות בכל יום בעולם הטכני שלנו ואם בנות לא ילמדו יסודות התורה מן
>   החומש ומן הגמרא עם פירושי הראשונים אז ח"ו תפסיק היהדות האמיתית שלנו
>   הגענו לזמן ש"נשים באות לשמע" ואז יתגשם ויתקיים סוף הפסוק (הכתוב בפרשת
>   הקהל) "ושמרו לעשות את כל דברי התורה הזאת" [מתוך מאמרו של דודי הרמ"א
>   מאזעסאן שיחי' בהדרום אלול תשנ"ח עמ' ס"ה-ס"ו והשוה דרשת רבנו שנדפסה
>   בבית יוסף שאול חוברת ד' עמ' פ"ג-פ"ד

R. Soloveitchik also wrote two letters to R. Leonard Rosenfeld (the second one was cited by Curiouser [above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7074/13438)).

***[Community Covenant and Commitment](https://books.google.com/books?id=p611GgXAUdMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=community%20covenant%20and%20commitment&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3bWw1dbbAhVGwVkKHRxzB70Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=community%20covenant%20and%20commitment&f=false)* p.81**

> Dear Rabbi Rosenfeld,
>
> I acknowledge receipt of your letter. In my answer to your previous
>   inquiry concerning the permissibility of instruction of girls in
>   Talmud I stressed that unless I am assured in advance by the school
>   administration that my recommendations will be followed I would not
>   take the trouble to investigate the matter. Since such an official
>   assurance has been withheld (your letter did not contain any such
>   commitment) I must decline to consider the controversial problem. The
>   reason for my reluctance to engage in this controversial issue is the
>   unique stand taken by many of our Jews on matters of Law and
>   tradition. We have reached a stage at which party lines and political
>   ideologies influence our halakhic thinking to the extent that people
>   cannot rise above partisan issue to the level of Halakhah-objectivity.
>   Some are in a perennial quest for “liberalization” of the Law and its
>   subordination to the majority opinion of a political legislative body,
>   while others would like to see the Halakhah fossilized and completely
>   shut out of life. I am not inclined to give any of these factions an
>   opportunity for nonsensical debates.

***[Community Covenant and Commitment](https://books.google.com/books?id=p611GgXAUdMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=community%20covenant%20and%20commitment&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3bWw1dbbAhVGwVkKHRxzB70Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=community%20covenant%20and%20commitment&f=false)* p. 83**

> Dear Rabbi Rosenfeld:
>
> Please accept my apologies for not answering your letters sooner. The
>   delay was due to my overcrowded schedule. As to your question with
>   regard to a curriculum in a coeducational school, I expressed my
>   opinion to you long ago that it would be a very regrettable oversight
>   on our part if we were to arrange separate Hebrew courses for girls.
>   Not only is the teaching of Torah she-be-al peh to girls permissible
>   but it is nowadays an absolute imperative. This policy of
>   discrimination between the sexes as to subject matter and method of
>   instruction which is still advocated by certain groups within our
>   Orthodox community has contributed greatly to the deterioration and
>   downfall of traditional Judaism. Boys and girls alike should be
>   introduced to the inner halls of Torah she-be-al peh.
>
> I hope to prepare in the near future a halakhic brief on the same
>   problem which will exhaust the various aspects of the same. In the
>   meantime I heartily endorse a uniform program for the entire student
>   body.

Additionally, R. David Holzer records a similar response from R. Soloveitchik as well as another argument that he advanced, based on the fact that women are certainly no worse than converts:

**[The Rav Thinking Aloud p. 121](https://books.google.com/books?id=2qtAAQAAIAAJ&dq=the%20rav%20thinking%20aloud&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=giyoress)**

> *[DH:] Can women learn Torah she'bal peh?*
>
> Yes. You can't really understand *chumash* or *hashkafas ha'yahadus*
>   without the interpretation and analysis of *Torah she'bal peh*.
>
> *[DH:] How do you explain "כל המלמד בתו תורה (כאלו) לומדה תפלות"?*
>
> Women also have to have the concept of *mesorah*. In the days of
>   *Chazal*, women got the *mesorah* through osmosis without formal learning, so there was no *chiyuv* for formal learning. It was based
>   on "שמע בני מוסר אביך ואל תטש תורת אמך". Today when our *mesoros* are
>   weak and they cannot get it through osmosis, they still have two
>   *chiyuvim*, to know the *halachos*, to know what to do ללמוד לעשות; and the love of *Torah she'bal peh* so they can pass it on to their
>   children.
>
> The proof is from a *giyoress*, who must be taught *ikarei ha'das*
>   including *mussar* and *hashkafas ha'chaim*. Our daughters today are
>   certainly no worse than *geirim*, who need *limud*. Why would Rashi
>   and Ramban be OK, but gemara not? They're all *Torah she'bal peh*.

Another argument advanced by R. Soloveitchik is recorded by R. Moshe S. Gorelik:

[***Memories of a Giant* p. 181**](https://books.google.com/books?id=-dfXAAAAMAAJ&dq=memories%20of%20a%20giant%20%20reflections%20on%20rabbi%20dr.%20joseph%20b.%20soloveitchik%20zt%22l&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=incumbent)

> I once heard him [R. Soloveitchik] declare that since women are
>   obligated to study *mitzvos* which are incumbent upon them, then much
>   of the Talmud is required for study.

Another authority to advocate that the changing times require  women's Talmud study was [R. Yehuda Amital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Amital). R. Reuven Ziegler records the following story:

**[*Tradition* 43:3 p.81](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/0081-0088.pdf)**

> In 1995, I was present when R. Amital told a gathering of the kollel
>   that he did not feel women needed to study Talmud; his grandmother and
>   mother had been very pious Jews without it. A year or two later, he
>   addressed a women’s learning program with the words, “You know, I used
>   to think that Talmud study for women was unnecessary, but now I think
>   it is absolutely essential!” Soon afterwards, Yeshivat Har Etzion
>   decided to open a women’s division in Migdal Oz, where Talmud study is
>   a major part of the curriculum.

A final argument is that there can't have been a full-blown prohibition on women studying the Oral Law, because we find that throughout history there have always been individual learned women. R. Yissaschar Tamar in his commentary (Alei Tamar) to the passage in the Jerusalem Talmud lists off a dozen or so such women.<sup>1</sup> Indeed, the [Sefer Hachinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) in discussing the prohibition of issuing a halachic ruling while drunk, says that this prohibition also applies to women who are capable of ruling:

**Sefer Hachinuch # 152**

> ונוהג איסור ביאת מקדש בשכרות בזמן הבית בזכרים ונקבות ומניעת ההוראה בכל
>   מקום ובכל זמן בזכרים וכן באשה חכמה הראויה להורות

As it is inconceivable that someone could rule without ever studying Talmud, this indicates that it is at least possible for individual women to study Talmud.

However, other authorities have argued that the ban on women's Talmudic studies is still in force. [R. Joel Teitelbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Teitelbaum) referred to those who cite R. Kagan's statement as permitting that which the Sages forbade as idiots. He argues that the law can never change, and R. Kagan only mentioned areas of study that were not formally prohibited, but merely customarily not studied by women. But areas of study that were formally prohibited to women (including Talmud and even Rashi's commentary to Chumash) are still absolutely forbidden:

**Vayoel Moshe 3:48**

> ויש טפשים התולים בדברי החפץ חיים ז"ל שכתב בס' ליקוטי הלכות שלו במס'
>   סוטה בהלכות האלו שאסור ללמד תורה לנשים והביא פרטי הדינים ונכתב בצדו
>   ונראה דכ"ז בזמנים שלפנינו וכו' שקבלת האבות הי' חזק מאוד וכו' היינו
>   יכולים לומר שלא תלמוד תורה ותסמוך בהנהגה על אבותי' הישרים אבל כעת
>   בעו"ה שקבלת האבות נתרופף מאוד מאוד וכו' מצוה רבה ללמדם חומש וגם נביאים
>   וכתובים ומוסרי חכז"ל וכו' כדי שיתאמת אצלם ענין אמונתנו הקדושה וכו'
>   והנה תלו סוקי סרוקי והוצאת שם רע על אותו צדיק כאילו ח"ו אמר על הלכה
>   פסוקה שהוא מן הש"ס והראשונים והשו"ע שאינו נוהג בזמננו וח"ו לעקור הלכה
>   פסוקה אבל עינים להם ולא יראו מ"ש ללמדם חומש ונו"כ ומוסרי חז"ל וכל אלה
>   שחשב אין בהם איסור מצד הדין כמו שנתבאר לעיל אלא שבכמה דורות נהגו
>   סילסול שלא ללמד לנשים כלל והי' בזה טעמים או חששו שלא יומשך עי"ז ללמדם
>   אח האסור להם ולכן סמכו בכל מה שצריכות לידע על קבלת האבות כמו שנראה
>   מדברי המהרי"ל וע"ז כתב שלפי מצב הדור שנתרופף הקבלה וא"א לסמוך על קבלת
>   האבות מצוה ללמדם את המותר ללמוד עמהם מצד הדין אלא שהיו נמנעים לכתחילה
>   בדורות שלפנהו אבל לא להתיר ח"ו את האסור מדינא ובמה שאמרו חכז"ל דהוי
>   כמלמדה תיפלות ק"ו ב"ב של ק"ו בדורינו החלש שמזיק יותר יען שנתרופף דרך
>   האבות והנה כתב ללמדם חומש אבל לא כתב עם פירש"י ז"ל שזה ודאי איסור גמור
>   ללמדם כי דברי רש"י ז"ל הן הן גופי תורה ועומק דרשת חז"ל דהוי ודאי בכלל
>   מה שאמרו חכז"ל שהוא כמלמדה תיפלות

[R. Yaakov Weinberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Weinberg) also strongly objected to women studying Talmud nowadays, and went so far as to say that it would be better for schools to not teach Talmud to boys either rather than teach Talmud to girls:

**[Rav Yaakov Weinberg Talks About Chinuch p. 126](https://books.google.com/books?id=4w4mAQAAIAAJ&dq=rav%20yaakov%20weinberg%20talks%20about%20chinuch&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=b%27ezer)**

> In terms of the specific question that was asked, if I had to answer
>   it, I would say that it is better that boys never see a Gemara than to
>   teach it to the boys and girls together. It is far, far better. The
>   boys will survive not having seen a Gemara. *B'ezer Hashem Yisbarach*,
>   they will come to a yeshivah and will start learning it, with a
>   certain handicap, of course. They would have been able to do better if
>   they had seen a Gemara, but they will survive. But teaching girls
>   Gemara – that they will not survive. If you have to make a choice of
>   either not teaching the boys and the girls or of teaching both, make
>   the choice of teaching neither. You will be much better off in terms
>   of building *Yiddishe neshamos*.

---

### In sum

Most classical authorities codified a rule that women should not be taught Talmud. There were a number of possible exceptions to this rule, and especially in recent times  a number of authorities have argued in favor of Talmud studies, while others maintain their strong objections. In contemporary practice there is a wide range within Orthodox Judaism. The more "modern" groups encourage women Talmud studies, and teach it in their schools. The average "yeshivish/chareidi" groups for the most part discourage it and do not teach it in their schools, but they probably wouldn't stop an individual girl from studying. The more intense yeshivish/chareidi, including many Hasidic groups, outright forbid it.

---

<sup>1. As I could not find anywhere to link the Alei Tamar, I have included the below images of the pages where he goes through the learned women throughout history. The third image is the most relevant one:</sup>

[image: Page from Alei Tamar]

[image: Page from Alei Tamar]

[image: Page from Alei Tamar]

[image: Page from Alei Tamar]

Comment: [Yeyasher kochacha!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/best-answer-contest-winner-fourth-quarter-of-5778)

Comment: I'd be curious to see you add [R' Willig's statement](https://www.torahweb.org/torah/2015/parsha/rwil_ekev.html) into this answer and contextualize it, if you feel like it.

Answer (score 20):

No, it is not assur.

> As to your question with
>   regard to a curriculum in a coeducational school, I expressed my
>   opinion to you long ago that it would be a very regrettable oversight
>   on our part if we were to arrange separate Hebrew courses for girls.
>   Not only is the teaching of Torah she-be-al peh to girls permissible
>   but it is nowadays an absolute imperative. This policy of
>   discrimination between the sexes as to subject matter and method of
>   instruction which is still advocated by certain groups within our
>   Orthodox community has contributed greatly to the deterioration and
>   downfall of traditional Judaism. Boys and girls alike should be
>   introduced into the inner halls of Torah she-be-al peh.

R. Joseph B. Soloveitchik, Community, Covenant, and Commitment:
Selected Letters and Communications, p. 83

Comment: If you were to quote, say, the _Minchas El'azar_ to the same effect, it might influence the reader more. Not that Rabbi Soloveitchik is not authoritative, of course.

Comment: R' Soleveichik's point is shared by the vast majority of bais yaakov schools and is the basis for the study of Rashi and other meforshim, which include midrash and other torah shebeal peh.  R' Soleveitchik put forward to extend the application of this principle to gemara as well.  On a personal note, while I think R' Soleveitchik's point is well grounded, it is a monumental change from our tradition (note: I didn't say halacha), which is looked upon very warily.

Comment: @msh210 Why is the Minchas Elazar more authoritative? Did he run a school for girls where this question was actually practical?

Comment: It would probably be more generally useful to include RYB"S's reasoning along with his final opinion.

Comment: @Isaac: if the question was "why is it not prohibited..." then I could see including all sorts of reasoning. But the question was "is it assur?" in which case all that is needed is a gadol b'Torah who answered the question, l'maaseh.

Comment: @R'Curiouser, re your question to me: He may be more authoritative, but that's not what I said (or meant). I meant only that he is known for his strong opposition to modern trends.

Comment: @Curiouser - Just including the bottom line only answers the question "Is it assur according to this gadol?" Including his reasoning helps answer and understand the more general question "Is it assur?" Also, even if the question is posed as yes/no, it's much more useful to readers to have the answer include information about why. The purpose of this site is to share information, not to render pesak.

Comment: @Isaac Every halachic answer is "according to this gadol" -- there are very few (if any) issues with universal agreement. R. Soloveitchik's reasoning is that "discrimination...has contributed greatly to the deterioration and downfall of traditional Judaism". If you don't find his reasoning rigorous enough, that's one thing -- but he is quite clear that the reason for the imperative to educate girls in Talmud is that failure to due so was hurting Traditional Judaism. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Curiouser, For the most part, Halachic discussions tend to appeal to sources as part of their reasoning. The question of the advisability of teaching TShB"P to women, perhaps, isthe question  more of a policy question than a Halachic question, and therefore is more dependent on the opinion and policy reasoning of contemporary gedolim. However, the question at hand, "is it assur," sounds more like a cut-and-dry Halachic question which would be answered by engaging with whatever sources (which I agree with WAF would be good in the question) people quote to indicate issur.

Comment: ... "There is no source saying that it's assur." could potentially be a worthy answer, in this case. I suppose that a gadol saying that it's advisable would seem to imply that this is the case, or at least that the sources quoted toward issur are dismissable. (Of course, I'm dancing around the point that AFAIK, the strongest source for "Issur" is a gemara that doesn't really make a halachic statement.)

Comment: -1 Harav Solevecik was not a Posek (The Rav thinking aloud by Yedidi Hayakar Harav David Holzer Shelit"a).

Comment: @HachamGabriel I assume you're aware that not only did that book publish recordings of the Rav that he did not know would be published, but it was published against the explicit requests of the Rav's remaining family. I can personally testify that the Rav's daughter complained extensively when it was published. Finally, I'm not sure what david holzer intended, but by all means the Rav was certainly qualified to and in practice did many times issue psakim, so I don't see why this answer is not useful, especially when we see the Rav acted on this psak, so he certainly intended it to be lemaaseh.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Looking now I don't see the word 'posek' anywhere on this page, so I'm not sure why it matters what titles different people assign to others. Do you really think the Rav was unqualified to issue a psak?

Comment: @DoubleAA the words used are his own. I don't know how he used this lemaaseh because he clearly stated he is not a Posek. BTW was not aware of that.

Comment: What's the difference if he is a *poseik* or not a *poseik*?  The words of a *gadol* carry weight, even if they aren't intended as *pesak*.

Comment: @AdamMosheh All the more so here, where they clearly were intended as psak, as the Rav himself gave the opening gemara shiur to the women's Talmud program at Yeshiva University.

Comment: @doubleaa he's not the only rabbi that held this. See the hida I quoted meaning yesh al mi lismoch.

Comment: @msh210 the Dvar Avraham of Kovma wrote "halach k'moso b'chol makom" about R. Soloveitchik.

Comment: Why would they learn gemara of they have no mitzva to learn it? What would they gain by doing so?

Answer (score 20):

The Igros Moshe [YD 3:86](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=332&hilite=) says that the Chachamim commanded that women should not be taught  Mishna since it is oral Torah and it is like teaching them tiflos(promiscuity) and it should be avoided. However, they can be taught  Pirkei Avos since it has Mussar (instruction) and has hanhagos tovas (good deeds).

In The Sefer VaYoel Moshe(Satmer Rebbe) [Maimer Lashon Hakodesh 33(page 436)](http://www.mysatmar.com/docs/shite_hakdoshe/vayoel_moshe.pdf) says teaching Rashi to girls falls into the category of teaching tiflos and is an issur chamer Meod(very great sin).

There are those who make a distinction between a classroom setting and learning by oneself. Like Hacham Gabriel pointed out from the Chida [Tuv Ayin 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1920&st=&pgnum=8) (read inside how he learnt the Rambam).

For a more in depth anaylasis of this topic see the [Tzitz Eliezer 9:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14508&st=&pgnum=42)

Answer (score 16):

According to the Hida (Shu"t Tov Ayin #4) we may not force women to learn Torah (as we do Yeshiva students-see Sefer HaHinuch Behar 343). He says women may learn on their own, but adds we **can** teach her (not against her will).

Comment: Do we force MEN to do any other mitzvot aseh (assuming nobody else is affected)?

Comment: There are numerous sources for forcing men to do mitzvos. The same section of Shulchan Orekh forbidding teaching women deals with how and when to force men to do so.

Comment: This was the opinion of R' Yaakov Weinberg, based on the Rambam.

Comment: Could you quote Chida?

Answer (score 9):

An interesting data point. In [Lubavitcher Rabbi's Memoirs](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15617&pgnum=211) describes a woman named Devorah who grew up in Minsk where women were better educated, and she herself learned Gemarra with Rashi by the age of 15 (and had friends who were women who were apparently at a similar level that she studied with).

When she re-married (she was widowed at a young age) and moved to Vitebsk, she was dismayed at the relative ignorance of the women there and looked to educate them. Ultimately she worked to attract many Torah scholars to that city and made it a center of Torah learning, and founded a Yeshiva bearing her (and her daughter's) name.

I believe the time-frame discussed is 17th century.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Why?

Comment: @DonielF because it doesn't answer the question... it tells a nice story about women learning.  If it concluded with the lubavitcher rebbe's opinion, or the reasoning as to why the woman acted in this manner, it would be a fine answer.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות The question asked if women could learn Gemara, and this answer tells a story in which women learned Gemara under Rashi quotes by the Lubavitcher Rebbe - is that not a firm yes? The question didn’t ask for a reason, just a simple yes-or-no question with sources. I don’t see how this doesn’t satisfy those criteria.

Comment: It's not a firm yes at all (it doesn't even say that in the answer!)  Plenty of people quote plenty of inspirational stories, and they don't necessarily agree with the final Halacha. I feel that answers [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73153/what-was-the-lubavitcher-rebbes-position-on-womens-gemara-study) about the actual opinion of the Lubavitcher Rebbe  are much more fitting to answer this question.

Answer (score 7):

While few Orthodox authorities openly say that teaching the oral tradition to women is forbidden many *do* say that the should not be taught Gemara and/or that there is no commandment to do so.  Examples include the Maharil and R' Moshe Feinstein, not to mention Hasidic authorities. Modern Orthodoxy , and especially the more liberal streams of Judaism, do not see this as an issur in light of changing societal norms regarding women. For a deeper discussion of this issue and numerous primary sources see [this article](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mishpach/maamad/talmud-2.htm) (Hebrew only)

Comment: What if my posek is Rav Ovadia Yosef, or Rav Bentzion Abba-Shaul or Rav Ovadia Hadaya or Rav Yosef Kaphach or Rav Mordechai Eliyahu or Rav Ezra Attia or one of the many many many other poskim I may legitimately follow whose opinion you neglected? This isn't necessarily a psak halacha for me! Why is your answer any better than HachamGabriel's?

Answer (score 5):

The [Riaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_di_Trani_the_Younger) (13th cent.) writes that there is no prohibition in women learning Torah or in teaching them. He does not differentiate between different categories of Torah, and implies that it is all permissible:

> פסקי ריא"ז מסכת סוטה פרק א - המקנא
>
> ב. אף על פי שאין האשה מצווה על תלמוד תורה כמו שנ' ולמדתם אותם את בניכם, ולא את בנותיכם, אם רצה ללמדה הרשות בידו כמבואר בקונטרס הראייות בראיי' ב'
>
> Even though a woman is not commanded in *talmud Torah*, as it says 'And you shall instruct your sons in them' (Deut. 11:19), and not your daughters, if he wanted to teach her, he is permitted as is explained in *Kuntres HaRaayot: Raaya 2*.

Answer (score 0):

No, women should learn Torah. It is important to understand that learning Talmud doesn't make one a rabbi and that women still cannot become rabbis. Learning Torah on the other hand should never be discouraged.

Please see the following articles:

[Putting Women in the Picture](http://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/161694/jewish/Putting-Women-in-the-Picture.htm)

[The Rebbe’s Clever Position On Teaching Gemara To Women](http://www.transformative-judaism.com/the-rebbes-clever-position-on-teaching-gemara-to-women/)

Comment: Adding sources would improve the value of your claims.