# What was the Lubavitcher Rebbe's position on women's gemara study?

Tags: talmud-gemara, women, torah-study, chabad

It is my understanding that women's gemara study [is rabbinically prohibited](https://www.nishmat.net/torah/view.asp?id=44). However, I keep hearing that the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l had an interesting, perhaps liberal position regarding women's study of gemara.

But I don't know exactly what it was, and pages like [this](http://www.transformative-judaism.com/the-rebbes-clever-position-on-teaching-gemara-to-women/) do little to clear up the confusion. What was it?
Did the Rebbe have--and/or does Chabad today have--an "official" position regarding the permissibility of gemara study for women?

(I am interested both in the most recent Lubavitcher Rebbe's position on this issue, and--insofar as it might be subtly different--in the holistic Chabad view, i.e., including positions of the previous Rebbes. I would also like to know what Chabad does in practice with this information; as far as I understand, it is a bit of a mixed bag, insofar as mainstream Chabad women learn Ayn Yaakov but not general gemara, but certain Chabad institutions have and do teach women gemara itself, if I am not mistaken. Can anyone confirm or refute?)

Related: [Is it forbidden for a woman to learn Gemara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/is-it-forbidden-for-a-woman-to-learn-gemara)

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe isn't the only one to say women can / should learn gemara, many other great rabbi's are of the same opinion, [read more here](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/are-women-permitted-to-study-gemara-by-rabbi-howard-jachter)

Comment: related to this subject... https://derher.org/wp-content/uploads/82-sivan-5779-teaching-torah-to-women.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I'd say "discouraged", not "prohibited." Generally, women should have the Torah background that they need to function. It's the pure, theoretical pursuit of knowledge that gave Chazal pause.

I'm told the Seventh Rebbe zt"l felt that some basic exposure to Gemara today is considered material that's needed to function, and therefore allowed and even encouraged. That may mean a few pages of practical material about Shabbos, Pesach, or Brachos to understand the halachic process behind them; not necessarily spending six months on *Takfo Kohen* or *Shev Shmaytsa* (if you don't know what those are, don't worry about it).

Rabbi Rakeffet has an mp3 about a meeting between the Lubavitcher Rebbe and a younger Belzer Rebbe where they're agreeing about the need for more textual exposure for the daughters of their communities, including some Gemara. If I recall correctly, a recording of that discussion is available.

It's not really that radical of a position.

Comment: R' Berman was party to that meeting and he has said that women should learn gemara for yirat Hashem and that their learning should cover all of the mitzvot they were required to fulfil. Many Chabad rebbetzins I know learned from actual masechtot, rather than printed sheets when they were in [whatever Chabad calls their Beis Yaakov schools].

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Beis Rikvah

Comment: `I'm told the Seventh Rebbe zt"l felt...` Told by whom?

Comment: @mevaqesh sorry -- a Lubavitch shliach with whom I'm friendly. He's now probably in his early 60s -- if that helps identify which generation. (I.e. he began his shlichus well before the rebbe's stroke.)

Comment: https://derher.org/wp-content/uploads/68-Iyar-5778-06.pdf some of the conversation between the Rebbe and the Belzer Rebbe

Answer (score 5):

I learned from Rabbi Levke Kaplan of Chabad that the Lubavitcher Rebbe said women should study Talmud "without limitation."

I have since heard another shiur where this was confirmed; apparently, the Lubavitcher Rebbe privately discussed his position (strongly supporting women's access to and study of all parts of the Talmud, if I understand correctly) with the Belzer(?) Rebbe, who disagreed. Their conversation has been documented but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 2):

Why women don’t learn gemara
In the days preceding Rosh Hashanah 5713  (1952),  the  Rebbe  received  a  group  of  university  students  for  a  joint yechidus  in  his  room.  After  a  few  words  on  the  significance  of the   time,   the   Rebbe   allowed   for   questions.
One     student     asked,     “Is     Torah     learning  equal  for  girls  as  it  is  for  boys?  Does  Lubavitch  offer  higher  education in Torah for girls, such as Talmud studies?
The Rebbe responded, “No. Men are obligated  to  study  Gemara,  but  not  women.
“The  reason  for  this  is  not  because  they  are  less  capable,  but  because  Hashem   has   entrusted   them   with   a  more  important,  loftier  duty,  and  they   are   therefore   absolved   from   learning Torah.
“That     holy     duty,”     the     Rebbe     explained,  “is  to  imbue  a  spirit  of  Yiddishkeit in the next generation. In order to allow them to do this, they are exempt from limud haTorah.”
(Teshurah Sandhaus, Shevat 5768)

http://www.merkazanash.com/sites/default/files/584%20-%20Rosh%20Hashana.pdf

look at the 2nd page 'a moment with the rebbe'

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are more on point, but a quick, non rigorous mention of this by Rabbi Manis Friedman I once heard (topic was Basi Legani) is that in our days, before Moshiach, evil will be crazy. It will be insane, which means, going beyond reason. The response will be we will do insane good, going beyond reason, and mentions this is manifest in women learning these days. Women learning gemara is, therefore, considered a "crazy good" according to this story of the Rebbe, and "shtus d'kedusha" is a very lofty service in this ma'amar, and is a big concept in Chabad chassidus. I recently learned a ma'amar on it by the previous Rebbe.

Comment: Where are you seeing a connection between shtus d'kedusha and women learning gemera?

Comment: @Dude I am quoting, so I am not sure exactly what you are asking? Should I explain the connection?

Comment: I don't think anywhere in the maamar the Rebbe says women learning gemera is shtus dekedusha so where does Manis Friedman get this idea from?

Comment: @Dude heard it in person