# Sources that allow "important women" to be taught/learn Torah?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, women

The *Shulchan Aruch* ([YD 246](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.246?lang=bi)) codifies the law that women should not be taught the Oral Law. It seems it is also not the best thing to teach even the Written Law, but that if you do, it's not the same problem as teaching the Oral Law.

Regardless, while modern *poskim* like the Chofeitz Chayim, R. Yosef Dov Soloveitchik, and others have permitted teaching Torah to women based on various reasons, I recently heard the theory that the original "prohibition" against women learning/being taught Torah never applied to an *Ishah Chashuvah*. Following this logic, just about all women nowadays are considered to be *Nashim Chashuvos* (consider: the requirement for leaning at the Pesach Seder applies equally to women due to this fact) and thus all women can learn/be taught Torah without any concern for violating this original law in the Shulchan Aruch.

Trouble is, I have not been able to find any sources that discuss this particular idea. (I know of the commentary of the *Perishah* to the *Tur* where he picks up on the language of Rambam explaining that the prohibition applies only to "most women" and not women that choose to learn on their own, but that is not quite what I am referring to here. It's not nearly enough.)

Any help?

Comment: plural of ishah--nashim

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7074/11486

Comment: This question could be more compelling if you'd [edit] in more details about where you've heard of the theory you're asking for sources for.

Comment: There are sources that make exception for self-motivated women, but I'm unaware of a source that distinguishes in this regard between "important" women and other women. In fact, Rabbi Eliezer in the Y'rushalmi (*Sotah* 3:4) clearly makes no distinction and refused to discuss Torah with an aristocratic *matrona*.

Comment: I would urge you to take a listen to the following shiur given by Rabbi Moshe Meiselman, it can be found on yutorah with the following link:
https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/711895/rabbi-moshe-meiselman/women-in-halakha/
Also see part one chapter 7 in Jewish Women in Jewish Law authored by Rabbi Meiselman.