# Women and Oral Law

Tags: torah-study, women, oral-torah, written-torah

I see that there are numerous poskim who permit women learning the Written Torah, but not the Oral Torah. What I don't understand is that you can't understand the Written Torah without the Oral Law, and can't, in fact, fulfill the mitzvos properly. Are women supposed to be tzdukim/shomronim/karaim?  All of these are groups that our sages consider outside of normative Judaism. But surely Jewish women must be within Judaism, so...

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7071/13438

Comment: Surely these *poskim* permit learning halacha - is it not enough to fulfill *mitzvot* properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going into the issue of whether women should or are permitted to learn Oral Law, but it's worth pointing out that just because women *don't* learn Oral Law doesn't mean that women don't accept the *authority* of the Oral Law and Chazal. Tzedukim/Karaim/etc. rejected the authority of Chazal and the oral lineage of Torah Misinai. Jewish women do no such thing.

Comment: They may accept the authority of the Oral Law, but how does that help them implement the Oral Law if they are forbidden to learn what the Oral Law says?

Comment: They ask questions from those who learn and know what the Oral Law says, the same as I do when I don't know or haven't learned something.

Comment: It sounds like you’re rejecting the premise of the question that women are not permitted to learn Oral Torah.

Comment: I'm ignoring the premise, because I'm focusing on the inaccuracy of the assumption that follows. _You_ sound like Cathy Newman. :p