# Is it permitted to learn Torah with one's wife?

Tags: jewish-books, torah-study, marriage, women

Is it permitted to learn Torah with one's wife?

And if so, are there any special recommendations for what to study with her?

Generally speaking I understand that men don't take women as Chavrutas, related or otherwise.

Comment: Related (to the "what would be appropriate to learn" question): (1) "[Is it forbidden for a woman to learn Gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7071/1368)"? (2) "[Women and Oral Law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101339/1368)".

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that it wouldn't be permitted or appropriate? It's best to include whatever prior information you know, or whatever research you've done, so that you can get the best possible answer and so that answerers don't merely provide you with information that you're already aware of.

Comment: @Alex I have edited the question. The crux of it is that I haven't seen men learn with women outside of teaching their daughters.

Comment: @Finnegan that's probably because they don't often go to Shul to learn together but rather sit at home while the kids sleep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to prohibit learning Torah with one's wife, and indeed many husbands and fathers learn with their wives or daughters.

Recommendations for what to study is a personal preference, as the gemara in [Avoda Zara 19a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.19a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi says: A person can learn Torah only from a place
>   in the Torah that his heart desires, as it is stated: But his delight
>   is in the Torah of the Lord, i.e., **his delight is in the part of the
>   Torah that he wishes to study**.

Depending on the person, learning the parasha of the week, the meaning of the holidays, *emuna* might all be relevant. There are also certain areas of *halacha* which are critical to a woman, e.g., Shabbat, *kashrut*, *nidda*. Examples of books I have found helpful here are

- [Halichos Bas Yisrael: A Woman's Guide to Jewish Observance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568715277) which covers many women-relevant halachot
- [Children in Halacha](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066110.html)
- R Binyamin Forst's [The kosher kitchen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1422608972)
- R Daniel Braude's [Learn Shabbos in Just 3 Minutes A Day](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1988022304) is a very recent book which is structured along the 39 *melachot* and is both highly readable and quite deep
- [R Simcha Bunim Cohen's](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422615072.html) set of books on *Hilchot Shabbat* with each volume covering specific topics (e.g., the home, the kitchen, *muktze*, *amira l'akum*)

You can ask more specific questions if looking for recommendations in specific areas (e.g., *emuna*).

Comment: It all depends on how much time you want to spend in this Chavrusa. Another option to consider is Daf Yomi (or some other "Yomi" style study)