# Where can I find Rav Kook's writing of this?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chinuch-education, abraham-isaac-kook, non-religious

There is a [recent article](https://www.ou.org/life/inspiration/our-intense-focus-on-torah-education-is-celebrated-yet-its-flawed/) in which Rabbi Moishe Bane writes the following :

> The legendary Chief Rabbi Avraham Yitzchok KaCohen Kook z”l, observed
>   that in every society, in every religion, in every country, in every
>   era throughout history, there is a remarkable inverse correlation
>   between a community’s level of education and sophistication and the
>   degree of its religious intensity. The more educated a community, the
>   less vigorous its religious commitment. Is this observation not
>   evidence, asked Rav Kook, that religion generally appeals only to the
>   most primitive minds? Doesn’t this inverse correlation prove that we,
>   as sophisticated individuals, should recognize the folly of a
>   commitment to, and passion for, Torah Judaism?
>
> Rav Kook explained
>   that every society, in every religion, in every country, in every era
>   throughout history, provides their youth with roughly the equivalent
>   of a third grade religious education. Consequently, in those societies
>   in which that third grade religious education is accompanied by
>   a third grade secular education, the youth mature into adulthood
>   satisfied with their understanding of religion. By contrast, when a
>   community receives a third grade religious education, but then goes on
>   to receive a high school, university and an even more advanced secular
>   education, they consider the simplistic nature of religion, as they
>   had been taught, and dismiss religion as being primitive.

Where can I find Rav Kook writing such a thing?

Comment: Similar idea https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93116/759

Comment: Here are some facts: Hebrew isn’t the first language of the individual quoting R. Kook; said individual saw this piece 40 years ago (!); said individual is not exactly a ‘rabbi’ - if you get what I mean. Here is an observation: Given these facts people often misquote [albeit, unintentionally] and embellish. My point: You have a better chance sourcing the *original* quote from people much more familiar with R. Kook’s thought and oeuvre, e.g. R. Moshe Zuriel, R. Shlomo Aviner, Bezalel Naor et al.

Comment: @Oliver I'm going to go out on a limb here and kindly suggest your comment would be stronger without that little pinch of avek lashon hara regarding the president of the OU

Comment: I appreciate and surely accept your criticism; I didn’t know (kinda, still don’t) that there was *avak LH*. If I had to guess - you’re referring to the mention that the individual is not a rabbi in the traditional sense of the word/title. The purpose was to help recognize that the person who read the text forty years ago easily could’ve mis-understood/remembered/quoted what he read - this fact being one of the determinants.

Comment: @Oliver the avak lashon hara wasn't that he isn't a rabbi, but the rest of the wording (not exactly a ‘rabbi’ - if you get what I mean). E.g., if I were to say "Oliver isn't exactly a 'scholar' - if you get what I mean," you might rightly find it insulting

Comment: @wfb Oh. Didn’t cross my mind that it’d be construed that way. I meant it merely in the same vein as one wouldn’t consider a celebrity who received an honorary degree in a particular field to be qualified in that respective field.

Answer (score 9):

I have asked this question to R Moishe Bane, the president of the OU, and he responded

> Thanks for the interest. I came across Rav Kook’s thought in an essay
>   of his that I read in a rabbi’s home library in 1979. I have spent
>   hours searching for the journal and have yet to track it down. I
>   recall it was published in the second half of the 1920’s.

In a followup email where I told him I'd run it past two other scholars of R Kook he added

> I will owe you a big debt of gratitude if you locate the cite. I, too,
>   have run it by several Rav Kook scholars who did not know the article,
>   but found the message consistent with Rav Kook’s views and
>   presentation.

I then asked R Chanan Morrison about this - he translated lots of R Kook's writing into English ([ravkooktorah.org](http://www.ravkooktorah.org/)) who answered

> I also wondered what his source is. I am not familiar with such a
>   statement, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

and R Binyamin Tabady who told me this was in line with R Kook's thought but did not exist per se in writing.