# Will the Moshiach's Beit Din be "greater" than previous Batei Din?

Tags: messiah, beit-din-court, sanhedrin

The Gemara (Avodah Zarah 36a) says that a Beis Din does not have the power to overrule a Takkanah of a previous Beit Din. It is generally understood that earlier Batei Din are superior to later ones (due mainly to *yeridat hadorot*).

The Moshiach is going to be the [greatest individual to have ever been born (other than maybe Moshe)](https://aish.com/48944241/). Do we have any direct sources that state clearly that his Beit Din will be superior to all others?

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but I think the Moshiach's Beit Din should at least be greater than all preceding post-Talmudic Batei Din, by virtue of being a Beit Din Gadol (of 71 judges), where they will have been Batei Din Shel Yechidim (based on my reading of [the intro to Rambam's Mishneh Torah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.32?lang=bi&lang2=en)).

Comment: I’ve definitely seen places that say this explicitly, but I have to see if I can remember where I saw it. Here is a source that learns if from a yerushalmi, but it is not explicit in the source - https://har-habait.org/articleBody/32637

Comment: The Beit Din of Moshiach will be after the resurrection of the Yechidei Segulah. This means the very greatest of all previous generations (including Moshe Rabbeinu) will be members.

Comment: @YaacovDeane that answers my question very well

Comment: @YaacovDeane it's a machlokes what the order will be, and no one knows. Could be the Beis Din will be before techias hameisim...

Comment: @YaacovDeane is there a source for that? Seems very interesting.

Comment: @TamirEvan well I guess Tosafos (I think in Sukkah) does say that Moshe will be there when the Temple is rebuilt

Comment: @robev The Tosafos is in Bava Batra, if I recall. There is also discussion on Yoma 5a and Sukkah 52b. Outside of Shas, there are numerous sources among the Rishonim that discuss all of this. It’s not news. In the past on this site, I provided answers and specific traditional sources only to have them downvoted out of existence. It is a barometer of the level of Kaballat Ole in my view.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): "[When the Messiah comes, will Sanhedrin be able to overturn Gezairos (Rabbinic decrees) that are not relevant today?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/125812/1368)" (It asks: "Will Sanhedrin at the time of Moshiach be able to derive new halachos, and overturn previous ones based on applicability today?")

Comment: @TamirEvan yep that's a dupe, thanks